# What is a selective parameter in escape codes in ISO/IEC 6429:1992?

Tags: terminal, xterm, ansi-escape

According to ECMA-48/5th

```
8.1
Types of control functions
...
f) (Pn...): Control sequence with any number of numeric parameters
g) (Ps): Control sequence with a single selective parameter
...
i) (Ps...): Control sequence with any number of selective parameters
```

And for example set mode function is defined this way with `Ps...` paramters:

```
8.3.125
SM - SET MODE
Notation: (Ps...)
Representation: CSI Ps... 06/08
No parameter default value.
SM causes the modes of the receiving device to be set as specified by the parameter values:
1 GUARDED AREA TRANSFER MODE (GATM)
2 KEYBOARD ACTION MODE (KAM)
3 CONTROL REPRESENTATION MODE (CRM)
...
```

I wanted to test this function with xterm, but in xterm set mode function is defined differently ([link](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html)):

```
Pm   Any number of single numeric parameters, separated by ;
     character(s).  Individual values for the parameters are listed with
     Ps .

....
CSI Pm h  Set Mode (SM).
    Ps = 2  ⇒  Keyboard Action Mode (KAM).
    Ps = 4  ⇒  Insert Mode (IRM).
    Ps = 1 2  ⇒  Send/receive (SRM).
    Ps = 2 0  ⇒  Automatic Newline (LNM).
```

Could anyone explain what selective parameter is and the difference between selective parameters (`Ps...`) and any number numeric parameters (`Pn...`) in ISO 6429?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numbers in ECMA-48 are generally one of two types:

- something that lets an application ***select*** a feature from a list of options (e.g., selecting underlining or normal text from the list of *graphic renditions*), or
- something that lets an application specify the ***value*** of something (e.g., the number of rows by which to move the cursor)

That's been part of ECMA-48 since the mid/late-1970s.  Not everyone on the committee understood that.  Take a look at [this page](https://archive.computerhistory.org/resources/access/text/2019/02/102785372-05-02-acc.pdf), and search for "BSR X3.64" to see an example of the state of confusion by committee members on ECMA-48.

Comment: I had a blank in the url, from copy/paste.  Looks okay now.

Comment: Is the following statement correct: `Ps` is ALWAYS a number (that is index of the value from the list)?

Comment: The notational styles in xterm and ECMA-48 are different.   In a quick check, ECMA-48 uses *Ps* for selective parameter, while xterm uses it for single parameters.

Comment: I am asking about `Ps` in ECMA-48. I am writing a parser to work according to ECMA-48, and I need to know exactly if this `Ps` is always a number.

Comment: ECMA-48 appears to be using *Ps* consistently (as well as *Pn*): both are numbers.  Offhand, the controls which accept non-numbers are `APC`, `DCS` and `OSC`.  Look for *control string* to see the difference in the descriptions.  Pages 11-13 describe **parameters** and **control strings**.

Comment: Could you take a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71561226/what-are-7-bit-8-bit-environments-for-control-functions-according-to-iso-iec-6 ?