# What are 7 bit / 8 bit environments for control functions according to ISO/IEC 6429:1992?

Tags: terminal, ansi-escape

I am learning ECMA-48 and I see a lot of notes about 7 bit and 8 bit environments for control functions. For example:

> NOTE LS0 is used in 8-bit environments only; in 7-bit environments
> SHIFT-IN (SI) is used instead.

As I understand today all environments are 8 bits. If I am wrong could anyone give real examples where 7 bit environments are used.

Answer (score 1):

For example character encodings.

Standard uses values 0x00 to 0x1F, and 0x80 to 0x9F as C0, and C1 control codes. And uses control functions, control sequences, etc. which start from either ESC (0x1B) or CSI (0x9B).

In the 8 bit environment there must be some kind of encoding defined, which specifies which character is represented by which values. The first 128 values will be according to ASCII (or some other standard which is compatible (doesn't use 0x00 to 0x1F as printable characters but reserves them for C0 control codes)) but what about the next 128 values?

Here we enter the world of code pages, which define the upper 128 values. Some existing code pages (like ISO8859-2) reserve the values 0x80 - 0x9F for C1 control codes but some other ones (like CP1250) do not, and use them for printable characters.
When such an encoding is used it is not possible to use the values 0x80 - 0x9F simultaneously for both purposes (printable characters and control codes). So even though there are 8 bits, they are not available for the purposes defined by the standard.
So from the point of view of this standard we treat this as a 7 bit environment and so for example CSI (0x9B) becomes a sequence of 0x1B 0x5B.

"Ok, forget the code pages, we live in the future now. unicode rules".
Ok, with utf-8, the 8 bit encoding for unicode, the story is the same.
Values 0x80 - 0xBF (which includes 0x80 - 0x9F) are in utf-8 treated as the last byte of a character (actually, a code point, but that's irrelevant) encoded by multiple bytes. Again, a conflict.
So if the control functions from the standard have to coexist with utf-8, again 7 bit environment has to be assumed for the purposes of this standard.

(Actually, unicode (so also utf-8) does allow to encode the C1 control codes as valid unicode code points but then they will only work if interpreted by a program which is aware of unicode. Assuming 7 bits removes that requirement)

Your quote uses  LS0, SHIFT-IN (SI)
these are thigs defined in the ECMA-35 (ISO 2022) standard are a form of making it possible to encode more characters into the 7 or 8 available bits.
You probably don't have to deal with this part unless you actually want to support these kind of character encodings.